# How to expose a Kubernetes service on AWS using `service.spec.externalIPs` and not `--type=LoadBalancer`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I've deployed a Kubernetes cluster on AWS using `kops` and I'm able to expose my pods using a service with `--type=LoadBalancer`:

```
kubectl run sample-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80
kubectl expose deployment sample-nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
```

However, I cannot get it to work by specifying `service.spec.externalIPs` with the public IP of my master node.

I've allowed ingress traffic the specified port and used https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips as documentation.

Can anyone clarify how to expose a service on AWS without using the cloud provider's native load balancer?

Comment: Have you consider exposing this service using `NodePort`? Check this [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/) for that. This will open a port on you machines and you will able to access using theirs `IP:NODEPORT`. Remember also to edit security group of the nodes to allow traffic to that port.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `Loadbalancer` then you case use `NodePort` type of service.

[`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) exposes service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the `NodePort`). 
`ClusterIP` service that `NodePort` service routes is created along.  You will be able to reach the `NodePort` service, from outside by requesting:

```
<NodeIP>:<NodePort>
```

That means that if you access any node with that port you will be able to reach your service. It worth to remember that NodePorts are high-numbered ports (30 000 - 32767)

Coming back specifically to AWS here is theirs official document how to expose a services along with `NodePort` explained.

Do note very important inforamation there about enabling the ports:

> **Note:**  Before you access  **NodeIP:NodePort**  from an outside cluster, you must enable the security group of the nodes to allow
>   incoming traffic through your service port.

Let me know if this helps.